# Layout issue with "Your Sites" selector on Android App

Tags: bug, android-app

Excuse my brevity, posting from mobile.

I noticed this when trying to edit my saved site list -

The size of each list item is nearly the size of the screen itself.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Why yes it is. Thanks.